# how to increase the height of the list view while animating from bottom to top android?

Tags: android, animation

I have issue with how to expand the list view's height while animating it from bottom to top please give solution.i have used ,TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

Comment: Hi Rose, Did you found any solution for this issue. Please help me if you have any solution. I have raised Separate Question for the same issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452270/listview-height-issue-while-animating-from-bottom-to-top-android